# Change part of name attribute

Tags: jquery

How can I change only part of name attribute with jQuery?

For example if I have:

```
<input type="text" name="Sometext[1]">
```

How can I make jQuery to change `Sometext[1]` to `Sometext[2]`, then to `Sometext[3]` etc.
I have dynamic form fields, and I need each `name` attribute to be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
var i = 0;

$('input').each(function () {
   $(this).attr('name', 'Sometext[' + i + ']');
   i++;
});
```

Supposing you know "Sometext" !
If you don't know it, you'll have to guess it :

```
var i = 0;

$('input').each(function () {
   var input_name = $(this).attr('name').substring(0, $(this).attr('name').indexOf('['));
   $(this).attr('name', input_name + '[' + i + ']');
   i++;
});
```

And now, by reseting index when a new name comes:

```
var i = 0;
var input_name = null;

$('input').each(function () {

   var new_input_name = $(this).attr('name').substring(0, $(this).attr('name').indexOf('[');

   if (input_name !== new_input_name) {
       input_name = new_input_name;
       i = 0;
   }

   $(this).attr('name', input_name + '[' + i + ']');
   i++;
});
```

Comment: I think this is what elvis needed.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of input fields with different name attributes. I don't think it's a good idea to add each name in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you says, @elvis, but you can restrict the search within a specific form for example, like : $('form#my_form input').each (..).

Comment: Parhaps I didn't explain it quite good. Here is my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187592/jquery-add-array-sequence-for-dynamic-fields

Comment: From what I understand and cross referenced your questions, my solution seems to work, I go through all of your inputs, rename them from "some_name" to "some_name[{index}]", or, at least, send you in a potential way to do it. Maybe you'll have to reset the index when the name change, I'll update my answer for that.

Comment: Finally I got it to work, thanks to your example @cx42net :)   This is the line that helped me - $(this).attr('name').substring(0, $(this).attr('name').indexOf('[');

Comment: @CyrilN. dude.. this is pure genius creativity ! .. I wonder if that can be adapted also for a second level , e.g. `sometext[mytext][i]`

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
$('#inputID').prop('name','watever'); // v 1.6
OR
$('#inputID').attr('name','watever');
```

#### update

```
var i=1;
$('#formSubmit').live('click', function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {            
         $(this).prop('name',$(this).prop('name')+i); 
         i++;            
    });
    return false;
});
```

### [working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/aecdM/2/)

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to set "id" attribute of the element and then with jquery you can reference it and change any attribute you want like this:

```
$('#elementID').attr('name', 'whatever xxx');
```

You can also reference HTML element by using "class" attribute but you might get more than 1 element since more element can have the same class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
<input type="text" name="Sometext[1]" id="myInputEl">
```

You can change the value of name, using the following:

```
$(function() { // wait for the dom to be ready.
    // #myInputEl is reference to the ID.

    $('#myInputEl').attr('name', 'Sometext[2]');

});
```